# My Java program won't launch (.exe file)

Tags: java, jar, executable, launch4j

I have made a GUI based project which consists of 1 main class, multiple Object classes, and resource files (.png and .txt). I have extracted the project as a .jar file (via eclipse) and used that to crease a .exe file (via launch4J). However, when I run the .exe file, it does not launch.

Is it because it does not know which class to run (since there is no manifest file)? What would be some possible fixes?

Comment: plus 1 since the down-voter did not leave a comment why he down voted.

Comment: have you set a main class in the project ?.

Answer (score 0):

A manifest (or actually an `AndroidManifest.xml`) are files for Android systems.

While Android "looks and feels" like Java, it is actually another language. APK files are like a JAR, however, how they are processed and prepared is significantly different, since they are usually `DEX`ed and bit flipped for multiples of 4, they can appear "real jar" for a program, but their instructions are rubish, and have no meaning when executed.

A JAR file is a "Java Archive", and that is another whole concept.

Supposing that the executable was sourced from a correct APK project, then the launch4j should have failed creating the `*.exe`.

Supposing that the executable was sourced from correct JAR project, then the `main` is executted (and if its blank, it runs to completion, and ends). It appears as doing nothing, but executes its instructions.

Answer (score 0):

> go to run configurations from run menu.---> select java application
>   ---> select the project ---> select your main class ---> save the project ---> clean and build the application.

it seems like you haven't configured a main class for your project.

Comment: I went to the Run Configurations. Over there, the main class was already selected by default.